# Hibernate Avoid Duplicate Rows

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

**ER Dagram:**

[image: ER Diagram]

My Beans and Service class are given below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeBean implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int employeeid;

    @Column(name="EMP_NAME")
    private String employeeName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
    @JoinTable(name="EMPLOYEE_SKILLS",  
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", referencedColumnName="EMP_ID")},  
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SKILLS_ID")})  
    private Set<SkillsBean> skills;

    //Getters and Setters
}



@Entity
@Table(name="SKILLS")
public class SkillsBean implements Serializable {   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="SKILL_ID")
    private String skillId;

    @Column(name="SKILL_NAME", unique = true)
    private String skillName;

    //Getters and Setters
}

//Service Class with insert method
@Service
public class EmployeeSkillsServiceImpl {
      public boolean insert(String employeeName,String skills) {
            String[] skillNames = skills.split(SKILLS_DELIMITER);
            Set<SkillsBean> skillSet = new HashSet<SkillsBean>();
            for(int i=0;i<skillNames.length;i++){
                skillBeanObj = new SkillsBean();
                skillBeanObj.setSkillName(skillNames[i]);
                skillSet.add(skillBeanObj);
            }

            //Call DAO class now
            EmployeeBean employeeBean = new EmployeeBean();
            employeeBean.setEmployeeName(employeeName);
            employeeBean.setSkills(skillSet);
            employeeSkillsDAO.insert(employeeBean); //simple insert with hibernate session and flush
}
}
```

Requirement:
Recruiter can add Employee Name and Skill Names (comma separated) through UI (JSP page).

Current problem in steps:
Step(1) Recruiter enters 'Joe' and 'Java,Oracle', then:

> Employee table:

1 Joe

> Skills table:

1 Java 
2 Oracle

> Employee_skills table:

1 1
1 2

Upto here I am successful with out any issues, now the actual problem starts in step(2).

Step(2) Recruiter enters 'James' and 'Java' then, then I am expecting below records in tables, but I am facing an exception.

> Employee table:

1 Joe

2 James

> Skills table:

1 Java

2 Oracle

> Employee_skills table:

1 1

1 2

2 1

**Exception thrown in logs:**

> org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   insert: [com.esm.beans.SkillsBean] Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry 'Java' for key 'SKILL_NAME'

**This error clearly states that it is because of Unique constraint on SKILL_NAME, but I can't remove it as I don't want to 
insert the same skill name multiple times into skills table.**

*So how can I achive my desired output in the tables by modifying the EmployeeBean and SkillsBean beans ? What am I missing here ? *

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just before commit you can lookup in skills table if skill_name already exist take the same id and update to 'James'.

For example:

String[] skillNames = skills.split(SKILLS_DELIMITER);
            Set skillSet = new HashSet();

**//using Dao class to get all matching skillBeans

  //Subtract from the both lists(skillNames - existing skillNames)**

```
        for(int i=0;i<skillNames.length;i++){
            skillBeanObj = new SkillsBean();
            skillBeanObj.setSkillName(skillNames[i]);
            skillSet.add(skillBeanObj);
        }
```

Comment: I did not understand your logic, the point is I can't remove the skill from the employee as I have to save it into EMPLOYEE_SKILSS, where as I don't want to save it to SKILLS (because it is already existing skill)

Answer (score 0):

you need a little more logic in the for loop in your service :

```
        for(int i=0;i<skillNames.length;i++) {
            skillBeanObj = // find by name in skillsBean Dao

            if (skillBeanObj == null) { // not found in DB, create new skill
              skillBeanObj = new SkillsBean();
              skillBeanObj.setSkillName(skillNames[i]);
            }
            skillSet.add(skillBeanObj);
        }
```

Comment: This logic will not work as it will not add the new skill of the employee into the EMPLOYEE_SKILLS table.

Comment: why not ? ... we are always adding that skillBeanObj (found in DB or newly created one) into the skillSet ... so your EMPLOYEE_SKILLS table will be correctly populated ...

Comment: Pras has right. It will work correctly. To make it work faster you can hit database once and load all SkillsBean with given names and create only SkillsBeans for not found names.

Comment: @borysfan ... i won't do that ... ok if there is only 100 skills in DB .. but imagine  that skill table with a million rows in there ... nope, findByName with a good index on that name column is the best choice for me ...

Comment: @Pras In my opinion single hit to database will be more effective than checking all skills for given input one by one. Lets assume we have 1 million rows in skills table. Then user thries to assign 1000 skills to employee. 999 of these skills are already in databse. Loading 999 of them at once will be more effective than checking every 999 in separate query.

Comment: interesting ... but how to handle the missing one ? 1000 skills have been selected, 999 loaded from database ... you then have two "big" lists and you have to loop through those to create the missing one(s) ... what i don't really like is the "load everything from DB and loop through them" idea ... but you may be right ..